# Duplicate (Immitate) OpenCart Confirm Delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, opencart

I want to duplicate the OpenCart's jQuery to confirm action. This is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//-----------------------------------------
// Confirm Actions (delete, uninstall)
//-----------------------------------------
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Confirm Delete
    $('#form').submit(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('action').indexOf('delete',1) != -1) {
            if (!confirm('<?php echo $text_confirm; ?>')) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
        });
    </script>
```

The HTML is:

```
<a onclick="$('form').attr('action', '<?php echo $delete; ?>'); $('form').submit();" class="button"><?php echo $button_delete; ?></a>
```

My button is:

```
<a onclick="$('form').attr('action', '<?php echo $process_carts_action; ?>'); $('form').submit();" class="button"><?php echo "Process Carts" ?></a>
```

Is this the line that references the button and how?

```
if ($(this).attr('action').indexOf('delete',1) != -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, of course, simple.

```
if ($(this).attr('action').indexOf('delete',1) != -1)
```

The above code translates to (please correct me where I'm wrong)

```
if // IF
$(this) // this instance of the document object, form referenced by ID (#)
.attr('action') // which has been assigned an attribute named 'action'
.indexOf('delete',1) // we'll use the indexOf function to see if it contains string 'delete'
!= -1 // and if it doesn't return "-1", which means 'false'
if (!confirm('<?php echo $text_confirm; ?>')) //THEN 
// call the javascript 'confirm' function and fill it with text contained in php var $text_confirm
```

So the solution is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Confirm Process
    $('#form').submit(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('action').indexOf('process_carts',1) != -1) {
            if (!confirm("Are you sure you're ready to process all carts?")) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
 });
```

Where `process_carts` is a string unique in `#form` that is within the var `$process_carts_action`